# zsh : How to list directory content with tab?

Tags: shell, zsh

I just switched from BASH to ZSH and thing are pretty good, but:

when I start typing `cd /usr/share/s` and hit `TAB`, this is what I get:

```
$ cd /usr/share/sane/
sane/                   skype/                  ssl-cert/             
screen/                 smplayer/               strigi/               
seed-gtk3/              snmp/                   synaptic/             
sgml/                   software-properties/    system-config-printer/
sgml-base/              soprano/                sysv-rc/              
sgml-data/              sounds/                                       
simple-scan/            splashy/
```

And this is ok. If I then hit TAB again, I get `$ cd /usr/share/screen/`, the next candidate, which is also OK. (BTW, how do I cycle back to the previous candidate? Sorry, on to my question)

Now what if I want to see the contents of /usr/share/screen/ now? You know, BASH-style, `TAB TAB`? The cursor is at the end of the line, will I have to `ctrl-a` (or `home`), then `del del` (to erase `cd`) then `ls` then `ENTER`? That seems like a lot of typing. And it - possibly unnecessarily - enters the command in the history.

Would not there be a key (maybe modifier-TAB? but the obvious candidates are already taken by the desktop... I digress) that would tell zsh to stop cycling through `/usr/share/` and instead, just list the content `/usr/share/screen/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I get it now. I have to hit **enter** when */usr/share/screen/* is "selected" ; I guess it took me so long to understand because this is so far from BASH's behavior.

BTW, thank you for all your answers, people ;)

Comment: Wow, i've been using Zsh for a long time and wasn't quite sure how to do this :)